# NHibernate mapping by code ManyToMany

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

## Problem

I'm using NHibernate mapping by code to map relationships. In this case I map users to roles to privileges. Users and roles are in a n:m relationship, same for roles and privileges. The SQL DB is SQL Server.
If I remove the n:m relationshop from my code between roles and privileges, my code works. If it is there, I get the following `MappingException`:

```
Could not determine type for: 
Dtp.Entities.AppPrivilege, Dtp.Entities, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(id)
```

I can't find the source of the difference, since the same relationshop between users and roles works without a hitch. Can anyone shed a light on this problem please?

The precise part which produces the error (it goes away if commented out) is the Bag for `AppRole.AppPrivileges`.

## MyCode

### AppUser

~~~ Table ~~~

```
AppUserId, uniqueidentifier, not null
//some omitted properties
```

~~~ Entity ~~~

```
public class AppUser {
    public virtual Guid AppUserId { get; set; }
    //some omitted properties
    public virtual IList<AppRole> AppRoles { get; set; }
}
```

~~~ Mapping ~~~

```
public class AppUserMap : ClassMapping<AppUser>
{
    public AppUserMap()
    {
        Table("AppUser");
        Schema("dbo");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.AppUserId, map => map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
        //some omitted properties
        Bag(x => x.AppRoles,
            colmap => {
                colmap.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                colmap.Table("AppUser_AppRole");
                colmap.Key(x => x.Column("AppUserId"));
            },
            map => map.ManyToMany(many => many.Column("AppRoleId")));
    }
}
```

### AppUser_AppRole

~~~ Table ~~~

```
AppUserId, uniqueidentifier, not null
AppRoleId, uniqueidentifier, not null
```

### AppRole

~~~ Table ~~~

```
AppRoleId, uniqueidentifier, not null
//some omitted properties
```

~~~ Entity ~~~

```
public class AppRole{
    public virtual Guid AppRoleId { get; set; }
    //some omitted properties
    public virtual IList<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<AppPrivilege> AppPrivileges { get; set; }
}
```

~~~ Mapping ~~~

```
public class AppRoleMap : ClassMapping<AppRole> {

    public AppRoleMap()
    {
        Table("AppRole");
        Schema("dbo");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.AppRoleId, map => map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
        //some omitted properties
        Bag(x => x.AppUsers, 
            colmap => {
                colmap.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                colmap.Table("AppUser_AppRole");
                colmap.Key(x => x.Column("AppRoleId"));
            }, 
            map => map.ManyToMany(many => many.Column("AppUserId")));
        //The following definition produces the bug.
        Bag(x => x.AppPrivileges,
            colmap => {
                colmap.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                colmap.Table("AppRole_AppPrivilege");
                colmap.Key(x => x.Column("AppRoleId"));
            },
            map => map.ManyToMany(many => many.Column("AppPrivilegeId")));
    }
}
```

### AppRole_AppPrivilege

~~~ Table ~~~

```
AppRoleId, uniqueidentifier, not null
AppPrivilegeId, uniqueidentifier, not null
```

### AppPrivilege

~~~ Table ~~~

```
AppPrivilegeId, uniqueidentifier, not null
//some omitted properties
```

~~~ Entity ~~~

```
public class AppPrivilege {
    public virtual Guid AppPrivilegeId { get; set; }
    //some omitted properties
    public virtual IList<AppRole> AppRoles { get; set; }
}
```

~~~ Mapping ~~~

```
public class AppPrivilegeMap: ClassMapping<AppPrivilege> {

    public AppPrivilegeMap()
    {
        Table("AppPrivilege");
        Schema("dbo");
        Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.AppPrivilegeId, map => map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
        //some omitted properties
        Bag(x => x.AppRoles,
            colmap => {
                colmap.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                colmap.Table("AppRole_AppPrivilege");
                colmap.Key(x => x.Column("AppPrivilegeId"));
            },
            map => map.ManyToMany(many => many.Column("AppRoleId")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Another problem I just had with posting the question: Using the ### tags for marking a third level header (instead of the ~~~ used above), the Editor thinks to have found unmarked code and doesn't let me post it. Whom should I contact (and how) to take a look at this?

Comment: Try searching http://meta.stackoverflow.com/... somebody has probably already posted about that markdown issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem cannot be found in the files above. I just forgot to add the `AppPrivilegeMap` to the `ModelMapper` during `NHibernateHelper.OnConfigure()`.

Now the last task is to find out where to put the `.Inverse(true)`, so serializing an object won't result in an exception because of circular reference.